# What type of jar signing is acceptable for eclipse plugins?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm working on a couple of Eclipse plugins which, for business reasons, cannot be built on Eclipse Hudson servers. What are my options for signing these plugins so users aren't hit with a "You are installing unverified software" warning?

I've tried using `jarsigner` to self-sign plugin jars. `jarsigner` reports them as verified, but eclipse still warns that they're unverified when I try to install the plugins.

Most of the [documentation](https://wiki.eclipse.org/CBI#Signing_tool) I've found simply points to running signing goal on an eclipse.org machine, but this isn't feasible. [This page](https://wiki.eclipse.org/JAR_Signing#What_public_key_.28certificate.29_do_we_use.3F) indicates that independent signing is possible, but isn't clear as to what method is expected:

> Content made available on Eclipse.org will be signed with the
>   foundation certificate. Note this doesn't preclude other parties from
>   later signing the JARs with their own certificates.

What signing methods are trusted by Eclipse? Can I sign a plugin with my own certificate? If so, what type of certificate does it need to be?